# How to only run tests not having a certain tag in scala using flatspec through sbt?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, scalatest

As a scala beginner, I want to tag the integration tests in order to exclude them from running in certain scenarios (as they can be quite slow and might break due to external changes/problems).

I created the tag `integration` this way:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers, Tag}
object integration extends Tag("com.dreamlines.tags.integration")
```

In my test I tag a test like so:

```
class SchemaValidation extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  it should "return valid json" taggedAs (integration) in {
    ...
    assertSchema(response, endpointSchema)
  }
}
```

Yet when reading up on [how to filter certain tests based on the tag in the docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#filtering), I get highly confused as suddenly I read that I should be using  `org.scalatest.tools.Runner`

```
scala [-cp scalatest-<version>.jar:...] org.scalatest.tools.Runner [arguments]
```

which has the flags I am looking for:

> -l  specifies a tag to exclude (Note: only one tag name allowed per -l) -l SlowTests -l PerfTests

Yet I am only used to run my tests via:

```
sbt test
```

I have no idea what the scala test runner here is referring to or what goes on under the hood when I run `sbt test`. I am truly lost.

I was expecting to execute the tests not entirely unlike this:

```
sbt test --ignore-tag integration
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [sbt documentation on test options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Testing.html#Options) the following should work for you:

```
testOnly -- -l integration
```

Or in case ScalaTest uses the fully qualified tag id:

```
testOnly -- -l com.dreamlines.tags.integration
```

In case you want to do this by default, you can adjust the `testOptions` in the `build.sbt` file.

Edit:

You might consider [a different approach for integration test](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests). Instead of tagging them, you might want to put them in the `src/it/{scala|resources}` folders.

Comment: If run from commandline, I have to enquote the command: `sbt "testOnly -- -l integration"`